Why is resolving vectors in some ways WRONG?
The following question is from "Concepts of Physics" by H. C. Verma.

A man has fallen into a ditch of width $d$ and two of his friends are slowly pulling him out using a light rope and two fixed pulleys as shown in figure. Find the force when the man is at a depth $h$.


The answer is
$$\frac{mg}{4h}\sqrt{d^2+4h^2}$$ or $$\frac{mg}{2}\sec\theta$$
(As by FBD of fallen man, $F \cos \theta + F \cos \theta - mg = 0$. $F = \frac{mg}{2 \cos\theta})$.
Here we resolve the tension vectors to the vertical line.
Next question.
In the arrangement shown in the figure, the ends $P$ and $Q$ of an unstretchable string move downwards with uniform speed $u$. Pulleys $A$ and $B$ are fixed. The mass $M$ moves upwards with what speed?

Here we resolve the upward velocity $v$ of mass $M$ using either of the ropes. Let's take the left rope for instance. So, $v\cos\theta=u$ and $v=u/\cos\theta$.
And if we try resolving to some other axis, we get a wrong answer. Like in the same question above, if we resolve the velocity $u$ of the rope to the vertical, we get $u\cos\theta$ as the speed $v$ which is wrong and not $u/\cos\theta$? Why?

Just a side-note, if you use MathJax (as explained here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/) your equations may read a bit clearer.

this problem is hilarious. not the physics--that's fine, but the backstory is [emoji]

I am also solving this problem and I also made the same mistake. I've now finally understood what I got wrong and I think it will also benefit you:

So what you did was split $u$ into its components along the perpendicular and mistakenly thought that it was equal to $v$; these are two separate vectors in the same direction but have different magnitudes. This diagram clearly depicts that:

Clearly, $u\cos\theta$ and $v$ are parts of different right triangles so they are not equal. Infact, $v$ is greater between the two.

These mistakes are so subtle as we all are used to mugging up these things, it was very tough for me to find the mistake I did there. But the fight was worth it ;)!

EDIT: Since the questioner still had doubt why $2u\cos\theta$ is not a correct answer, here are two solutions for the given problem. The first one is the correct way to do it and the second is the wrong one:

In the first one, $v$ is divided into components, so we get $v\cos\theta=u$ for both sides of the rope, and hence $v=\frac{u}{\cos\theta}$.
In the second one (wrong method), $u$ is divided into components, so we get components of two of the $u$ from both sides of the rope adding up in direction of $v$, so we get $v=2u\cos\theta$.
Now, both the methods seem benign, but both give different results - so one of them must be incorrect. We know the first method gives the correct result because we have used the calculus method (as posted in another answer in to this question) and we got the same result.
I can not think of any other explanation than going for using the calculus method which seems to provide only one answer whatsoever. That way, both of the methods above used are only partially incorrect since in both the methods we assume that sum of components in a direction gives the other vector, which is only conditionally true. It came out to be true for first method, but not so for the second.

We can take an analogy with the FBD (free body diagram) method of adding forces. We add all the acting forces' to get a single resultant force. Now, we can divide all of them into components and talk about them component-wise.
i.e., sum of components in a certain direction of all the forces acting on a body = component of resultant force in that direction
When we apply this, we always take care of which are the applied/acting forces vs. which are the resultant forces. If we don't, we make mistakes just like the above one. One example of such mistake is this:

Here in the second method, similar to our original problem, there has been a mistake in finding which is the resultant vector - so we get a wrong answer. For forces, it can be easier to find the resultant vector, but for velocities - both the methods looked correct until we went to solve using the calculus method and one of the answers was clearly ruled out. Even if we try to consider $u$ as a resultant velocity and $v$ being the applied velocity - i.e. $v$ is causing $u$, it does not make much sense because clearly the pulling of the rope, i.e. velocity $u$ is causing velocity $v$. Turns out that for velocities here, it might not make much sense to talk about one being the acting and one being the resultant velocity.

Gist of all this: both method are in some terms incorrect and based upon assumptions which can not be verified by either of the method. Use calculus method instead as it is safer. Methods from NLM/FBD do not always work for velocities (i.e. DO NOT FORGET THE CHAPTER! YOU ARE STUDYING KINEMATICS, NOT LAWS OF MOTION!!!! ).

Hey, Thanks for your answer. I understand this quite well from your diagram. Could you clarify the last bit of my doubt? So, by your answer, I understand not directly but indirectly that if there was just one rope one side side, not the two as in the question, then the v of the box would have indeed been u cos theta?

I understad my orginal doubt but have developed another.Could you also explain why we can't add velocities of both the ropes together to get the final result. If we take left slanted river to be x axis then the sum of vectors will be root(u^2+u^2+2u^2cos 2 theta) = root(2u^2(1+cos2theta))=u root(4 root cos^2theta) = 2u cos theta. And if we calculate direction then let tanx = u sin 2 theta/(u+u cos2 theta) = tan theta, so tan x = tan theta, x = theta. So the resultant vector is in direction of theta from the left slanted rope which exactly fits but then why is magnitude wrong and 2 u cos theta?

I know it gets confusing since in FBD, you'd be easily taking the components of tension of the rope in any direction and it works out, since you know that the sum of all the components in a certain direction always equals to a component of the resultant in that direction. But here, $v$ is, in no shape, the resultant. So, you can't take component of $u$ in direction of $v$ and say $v$ is equal to that component. Slight difference in this case from the FBD.

Thanks Lakshay, I have understood now what you mean! But your explanation of v is not equal to 2u/cos theta was not what i asked. i asked why v is not equal to 2 u cos theta.

@KhushivBatra I've edited the answer. You can take a look and tell me if I was able to explain it to you now.

In the second problem, if the distance between pulley A and the mass M is $s$ then the height difference between the mass M and the pulleys is
$h = s \cos \theta$
The upwards velocity of the mass $M$ is then $u = - \frac {dh}{dt}$. Note, however, that we cannot conclude that
$\displaystyle u = - \frac {ds}{dt} \cos \theta = v \cos \theta$
because this implicitly assumes that the angle $\theta$ is constant. Instead we have
$\displaystyle u = - \frac {ds}{dt} \cos \theta - s \frac {d}{dt} \left( \cos \theta \right)= v \cos \theta + s \sin \theta \frac {d\theta}{dt}$
Let $y = s \sin \theta$. Since $y$ is half the distance between the pulleys, it is constant, so
$\displaystyle \frac {dy}{dt} = 0
\\ \displaystyle \Rightarrow \frac {ds}{dt} \sin \theta + s \cos \theta \frac {d\theta}{dt}=0
\\ \displaystyle \Rightarrow \frac {d\theta}{dt} = \frac {v \sin \theta} { s \cos \theta} $
and so we have
$\displaystyle u = v \cos \theta + v \frac {\sin^2 \theta} {\cos \theta} = \frac {v} {\cos \theta}$

The components in chosen directions of a vector $\vec V$ are vectors in those directions that add (vectorially!) to make $\vec V$. In what circumstances does it make sense to add velocities? I can think of only two... (a) if we know a body's velocity in a frame S', and the velocity of frame S' relative to frame S, then adding these velocities gives us the body's velocity in S. (b) A body's velocity at time $t+\Delta t$ is its velocity at $t$ plus the extra velocity it acquires over $\Delta t$. There may be other cases where vector addition of velocities is called for, but your second pulley system is not one of them.
Although the slanting parts (length $s$, say) of the ropes in the second set-up are getting shorter (such that $\tfrac{ds}{dt}=-u$), their ends attached to M are not moving parallel to the slanting parts of the ropes; they don't have velocities at angles $\theta$ to the vertical. It's not a case of $\vec v$ being the vertical component of a vector $\vec u$.
Instead, let the instantaneous height difference between the top (approximately) of the pulleys and point of attachment of ropes to M be $y$, and the (constant) horizontal separation of the tops (approximately) of the pulleys be $2a$. Then
$$y^2+a^2=s^2$$
So
$$2y\frac{dy}{dt}=2s\frac{ds}{dt}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{that is}\ \ \ \ \ \ -v=\frac sy (-u)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{so}\ \ \ \ \ \ v=\frac u{\cos\theta}.$$


Here we resolve the upward velocity v of mass M using either of the
ropes. Let's take the left rope for instance. So, v cosθ=u and v=u/cosθ

You have incorrectly analysed this part. v is the adjacent and u is the hypotenuse, so the equation should be $\cos \theta = v/u \rightarrow v= u \cos \theta$. This is why you get a contradiction with your next result.
The most popular answer suggests we have to allow for the changing angle as the person is raised, but that is just over complicating things. If we are considering instantaneous velocities it is sufficient to consider only the instantaneous angle $\theta$.


Here we resolve the upward velocity $v$ of mass $M$ using either of the ropes. Let's take the left rope for instance. So, $v\cos\theta=u$ and $v=u/\cos\theta$.

I don't think these are correct.  The rope pulling diagonally is being pulled with speed $u$ (because it's wrapped around the pulley and that rope is being pulled down with speed $u$).  The vertical component of that diagonal motion is $u\cos \theta$, because $\cos \theta=\frac{\text{adjacent}}{\text{hypotenuse}}$, or written differently, $\cos(\theta)\cdot\text{hypotenuse} = \text{adjacent}$.  The $u$ speed is along the hypotenuse of the triangle and the vertical component is the adjacent leg.    If $v$ is the upward velocity, $v=u\cos \theta$, but you have written $v\cos \theta = u$.
If I may hazard a guess, the speed of the parts of the rope is labeled with $u$, but it happens to be that the thing you are looking for is an Upward velocity.  When I was reading the question, the fact that the variable name for an upward speed started with $v$ and a different speed started with $u$ gave me some trouble.  It may have given you trouble as well.
Also, I don't know if you did this in your notes, but it's helpful to draw a picture with the variables you are using.  Having an upward vector marked $v$ on the mass, downward vectors marked $u$ on the ends of the ropes, and diagonal up vectors marked $u$ (same speed) on the diagonals may help keep track of which variable is which.

I also had this doubt in me when i was studying NLM .
Whenever you have to resolve forces you always do them along and prependicular to the direction of motion
For example- in the first problem the man in the ditch will move upwards and the force of tension on him is on an angle , so you resolve them along the vertical so you take component T Cos θ and now T Cos θ is in the upward direction and mg is in downward so you can solve it easily .
Now for the 2nd question , the velocity u of the rope is already in the vertical so why do you have to resolve it ? You have to resolve only the velocity of the block along the rope so you can use u = v cos(θ)

Could you explain why its necessary that if velocity u of rope is already given, then we shouldn't resolve it. Could you also explain why we can't add the velocities of the 2 ropes vectorically to get 2ucos theta?
